Ag-Grid: Dragging from external div to a specific row on Ag-Grid
I am trying to drag-n-drop items from an external div to a specific row inside an Ag-grid, but not able to get the proper solution for this. In the Documentation, the example they provided is of drag-n-drop from one ag-grid to another and in that too they have taken ag-grid inside a div and used reference of that to drop inside the grid any any item dropped will be appended in the last, so in that case they are not considering a specific row drop.
link for that - https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-dragging-to-external-dropzone/
I am able to drag items from external div but not able to get the reference and the location of the row/Ag-grid where I need to drop that in order to add that item in the ag-grid.
